# Sitecore user profile data is null when using load balance url in non-sticky session

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

The application uses the sitecore membership provider to authenticate the user created in AD and Sitecore Profile provider to set the user profile data. These profile data are fetched from service and set during successful login. These user profile data are accessed in different page to perform some action. Ok. Everything is working fine in all lower environment where we have only one CD server.

But when we promoted code to pre-prod where it has 4 CD server, then it started giving problem. We could see that, User profile data are not being set or not being able to fetch. Below are the few information about our application, which will help you to understand the problem,

Session state : Outproc

Non Sticky session.

Host file entry made : 127.0.0.1 myFqdnUrl.com

Binding is in 80 port and i have to set
[image]

Update : The issue looks similar to this. 
https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/7934

Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without Sticky Session, subsequent request after login may go to different CD servers (based on Load balancing Algorithms) which will not have the logged-in session. IMO LB sticky session is needed if the session state is not SQLServer (or its equivalent).